# с помошью checkBox bolean , перекинуть предложение из textview со второго акивити в в пустоe textView первого акивити

Tags: android, kotlin, мобильная-разработка

всем привет! прохожу тему OnActivity Result android kotlin. как связать textview со второго акивити с предложением "bla bla bla" на пустое textview первого акивити с помощью checkboxa, кто нибудь может мне привести пример с кодом. то есть надо чтоб предложение из второго акивити textview.  предложение перекинулось на первое акивити textview

не выходит  это Main Activity `

```
    val texttv1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv1)
    val  texttv2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv2)
    val  texttv3 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv3)
    val  texttv4 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv4)
    val  texttv5 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv5)
    val  texttv6 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv6)



    val btnpage = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnpage)


    btnpage.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MoviesActivity::class.java)


        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)

        



    }

    val etData1 = intent.getStringExtra("tvinf")
    val chBox1 =  intent.getBooleanExtra("cb1",true)

    val etData2 = intent.getStringExtra("tv2")
    val chBox2 =  intent.getBooleanExtra("cb2",true)

    val etData3 = intent.getStringExtra("tv3")
    val chBox3 =  intent.getBooleanExtra("cb3",true)

    texttv1.text = etData1

    if (chBox1) {

        texttv2.text = "not choised"
    }
    else { texttv2.text = "choised"

    }

    texttv3.text = etData2

    if (chBox2) {

        texttv4.text = "not choised"
    }
    else { texttv4.text = "choised"

    }

    texttv5.text = etData3


    if (chBox3) {

        texttv6.text = "not choised"
    }
    else { texttv6.text = "choised"

    }






















 `
```

'  это второе акивити  `class MoviesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies)

    val textu = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textu)
    val chbt = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chbt)

    val textti = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textti)
    val chbLn = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chbLn)

    val texth = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texth)
    val chbbt = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chbbt)

    val btback = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btback)


    btback.setOnClickListener {
        val tv1 = textu.text.toString()
        val cb1 = chbt.isChecked
        val tv2 = textti.text.toString()
        val cb2 = chbLn.isChecked
        val tv3 = texth.text.toString()
        val cb3 = chbbt.isChecked

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("tv1", tv1)
        intent.putExtra("cb1 ", cb1)
        intent.putExtra("tv2 ", tv2)
        intent.putExtra("cb2 ", cb2)
        intent.putExtra("tv3 ", tv3)
        intent.putExtra("cb3 ", cb3)


        // startActivity(intent)

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
        finish()
    }

}
```

}
`

мне нужно чтоб предложение из textu со второго акивити вышло на первом акивити texttv1.text = etData1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос немного неоднозначно сформулирован. На мой взгляд самый простой вариант, это использовать обычный `Intent()` без `onActivityResult()`:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("your_text", text);
startActivity(intent);
```

и получение в целевой активности:

```
val text= intent.getStringExtra("your_text");
```

[Вот пример](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html) туториала с `onActivityResult()`. Чтобы передать данные мы в отправляющей активности делаем отправку данных (пример на java будет):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("text", text);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

добавляем в отправляющей активности обработку данных которые вам вернутся:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_ACCESS_TYPE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String accessMessage = data.getStringExtra(ACCESS_MESSAGE);
                textView.setText(accessMessage);
            }
            else{
                textView.setText("Ошибка доступа");
            }
        }
        else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

дальше в активности-получателе делаем обработку данных:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
TextView someView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ageView);
String age = extras.getString(MainActivity.AGE_KEY);
someView .setText("Данные: " +  age);
}
```

и так же `onActivityResult()` подразумевает что вы вернете какой-то ответ отправителю, что делается так:

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
```

или

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(MainActivity.ACCESS_MESSAGE, message);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

вот [первоисточник-туториал](https://metanit.com/java/android/2.11.php). Надеюсь это то что вам было нужно)) [Вот пример](https://devofandroid.blogspot.com/2018/03/pass-data-between-activities-using.html) работы с обычным intent.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня не вышло я не знаю что делать

Comment: вы не могли бы более подробно описать что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: например у меня второе Activity там на textview написано название фильма человек паук и checkBox с галкой выбрал не выбрал, второе text view бетман  и checkBox с галкой выбрал не выбрал, 3 textview Рублевка и checkBox выбрал не выбрал галкой . это все находится втором Activty и к каждому .   мне нужно сделать так чтобы. например я выбираю text view с названием Человек паук на 2 activity. чтобы он на mainActivty textview вышел что я выбрал человек паук фильм. без использования edit Text только textView. тоеть чтоб его название высветилось на main activity

Comment: тогда вам не обязательно использовать startActivityForResult а просто использовать обычный intent

Comment: ок но у меня фильм человек паук не высвечивается на mainActivity, а если убрать startActivity for result создается 3-4 вкладок main activity и второго акивити

Comment: не понимаю как может создаться несколько вкладок